# phpmyadmin sql dump to XML

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I am looking to convert specific database tables into an XML file through phpmyadmin. I have selected the data required and exported this, but if possible, I need to change the format of the XML file generated.

As is stands I get the following upon export from phpmyadmin:

```
<database name="awarddb">
    <table name="award">
        <column name="award_id">45</column>
        <column name="award_title">Name</column>
        <column name="award_description">Description here</column>
        <column name="award_img">image.jpg</column>
    </table>
</database>
```

What I am looking to do is export to the following format:

```
<awards>
    <award>
        <id>45</id>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description here</description>
        <img>image.jpg</img>
    </award>
</awards>
```

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score -1):

I don't think what you looking for can be covered by mysql.

You need to use regular expressions.